# Wordpress Plugin Development problem with script

Tags: javascript, php, wordpress, plugins

Hello I am creating a plugin for the very first time, I am using my stopwatch code already built-in PHP but my plugin is not working correctly, I think my script is not written correctly according to the plugin requirement, if understand please help me.

**Here is the code:
main plugin PHP file**

```
 <?php
/*
Plugin Name: MyStopwatch
Description: Adds a stopwatch to website
Version: 1.0.0
Author: Samina
*/
// Exit if acessed directly
if(!defined('ABSPATH')){
    exit;
}
require_once(plugin_dir_path(__FILE__).'/includes/stopwatchscripts.php');
function my_stopwatch_function(){
    return '<p id="output"></p>
<div id="controls">
  <button id="strtpause" onclick="strtpause()" class="stopwatchbutton">Start</button>
   <button id="reset" onclick="reset()" class="stopwatchbutton">Reset</button>
</div>';
}
add_shortcode('mystopwatch','my_stopwatch_function'); 
add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts','my_stopwatch_function');
?>
```

**script file:**

```
   <?php
    ob_start();
    //Add Scripts
    function stopw_add_scripts(){
    //Add Main CSS
    wp_enqueue_style('stopw-main-style',plugins_url(). '/mystopwatch/css/style.css');
    //Add Main JS
     wp_enqueue_script('stopw-main-script',plugins_url(). '/mystopwatch/js/main.js');   
    }

add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts','stopw_add_scripts');
?>
```

**main.js file**

```
var time=0;
    var running=0;
    function strtpause () {
        if(running==0){
            running=1;
            increment();
            document.getElementById("strtpause").innerHTML="Pause"

        }
        else{
            running=0;
            document.getElementById("strtpause").innerHTML="Resume"
        }
    }
    function reset(){
    running=0;
    time=0;
    document.getElementById("strtpause").innerHTML="Start"
    document.getElementById("output").innerHTML="00:00:00"
    }
    function increment(){
        if(running==1){
        setTimeout(function(){
         time++;
         var mins=Math.floor(time/10/60);
         var secs=Math.floor(time/10);
         var teths=time%10;
         if(mins<10){
            mins="0"+mins;
         }
         if(secs<10){
            secs="0"+secs;
         }
         document.getElementById("output").innerHTML=mins+":"+secs+":"+teths;
         increment();


        },100);
    }
    }
```

Comment: Put your js in some folder and wp_enqueue_script to call that script or just simply use hook for footer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fully working code and tested as well.[image]

```
<?php
/*
Plugin Name: MyStopwatch
Description: Adds a stopwatch to website
Version: 1.0.0
Author: Samina
*/
// Exit if acessed directly
if(!defined('ABSPATH')){
    exit;
}
ob_start();
// require_once(plugin_dir_path(__FILE__).'/includes/stopwatchscripts.php');
function my_stopwatch_function(){
    return '<p id="output"></p>
<div id="controls">
  <button id="strtpause" onclick="strtpause()" class="stopwatchbutton">Start</button>
   <button id="reset" onclick="reset()" class="stopwatchbutton">Reset</button>
</div>';
}
add_shortcode('mystopwatch','my_stopwatch_function'); 
add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts','my_stopwatch_function');


//Add Scripts
function stopw_add_scripts(){
//Add Main CSS
wp_enqueue_style('stopw-main-style',plugins_url(). '/mystopwatch/css/style.css');
//Add Main JS
 wp_enqueue_script('stopw-main-script',plugins_url(). '/mystopwatch/js/main.js');   
}

add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts','stopw_add_scripts');
?>
```

Comment: Still not working I do not know why it is not working giving me two errors, 1st is :

The plugin generated 2 characters of unexpected output during activation. If you notice “headers already sent” messages, problems with syndication feeds or other issues, try deactivating or removing this plugin.

2nd is:

Updating failed. Error message: The response is not a valid JSON response.

Comment: for header already sent please remove blank line from <?php
//Add Scripts
function stopw_add_scripts(){

Comment: and if still get error or header already sent then use ob_start(); after <?php

Comment: applied both but still having problems 2 characters is now changed to ! character I also checked all code there is no blank line left

Comment: kindly check now

Comment: I have updated the answer with tested screenshot just need two files there 1. MyStopwatch.php (Code updated in answer) 2. is js/main.js

Comment: If any issue comment, if working fine then approve the answer. :) Coding

Comment: Now the error is solved but my box is blank stopwatch is not running

Comment: can you help me about this why the stopwatch is not running

Comment: I am not sure why its not working from your end, please share a screenshot or error from the console so i can help you

Comment: Errors are solved now, but  stopwatch is not running

Comment: it is not picking my script from the main.js

Comment: if I write the script in same file them stopwatch starts running but again 
I face the Invalid JSON response error and the characters error

Comment: Did you changed anything from the answer i posted? just simply put main.js file inside js folder and put my answer to MyStopwatch.php and it will work.

Comment: i inspect the code and its not getting the main.js file, so that means plugin is not calling js file properly. add some test to your js to check in console log or simple alert

Answer (score 0):

you need to update your code like (I have tested )-

```
add_shortcode('mystopwatch','my_stopwatch_function'); 
add_action('wp_footer','MyStopwatch_scripts'); 

function my_stopwatch_function($watch_html) { 

    ob_start(); ?>

    <p id="output"></p>
    <div id="controls">
      <button id="strtpause" onclick="strtpause()" class="stopwatchbutton">Start</button>
       <button id="reset" onclick="reset()" class="stopwatchbutton">Reset</button>
    </div> <?php

    $watch_html = ob_get_contents();
    ob_clean();

    return $watch_html;

}

function MyStopwatch_scripts() { ?>

    <script>
    var time=0;
    var running=0;

    function strtpause () {
        if(running==0){
            running=1;
            increment();
            document.getElementById("strtpause").innerHTML="Pause"

        }
        else{
            running=0;
            document.getElementById("strtpause").innerHTML="Resume"
        }
    }
    function reset(){
    running=0;
    time=0;
    document.getElementById("strtpause").innerHTML="Start"
    document.getElementById("output").innerHTML="00:00:00"
    }
    function increment(){
        if(running==1){
        setTimeout(function(){
         time++;
         var mins=Math.floor(time/10/60);
         var secs=Math.floor(time/10);
         var teths=time%10;
         if(mins<10){
            mins="0"+mins;
         }
         if(secs<10){
            secs="0"+secs;
         }
         document.getElementById("output").innerHTML=mins+":"+secs+":"+teths;
         increment();


        },100);
    }
    }

     </script>
     <?php

}
```

if you create a shortcode you should use ob_start() & ob_clean() and js script normally working with wp_footer hook

Answer (score 0):

```js
 <?php
/*
Plugin Name: MyStopwatch
Description: Adds a stopwatch to website
Version: 1.0.0
Author: Samina
*/
// Exit if acessed directly
if(!defined('ABSPATH')){
    exit;
}
require_once(plugin_dir_path(__FILE__).'/includes/stopwatchscripts.php');
function my_stopwatch_function(){

ob_start(); //start output buffering
echo '<p id="output"></p>
<div id="controls">
  <button id="strtpause" onclick="strtpause()" class="stopwatchbutton">Start</button>
   <button id="reset" onclick="reset()" class="stopwatchbutton">Reset</button>
</div>';


//getting content after buffering
$content = ob_get_contents();
ob_end_clean();
return $content;
}
add_shortcode('mystopwatch','my_stopwatch_function'); 
add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts','my_stopwatch_function');
?>
```

If you have returned large string on php files before headers loaded to the page it displays on admin side "this plugin generated X characters of unexpected output"

You can add those returned strings to output buffering to prevent this error.

Comment: Just adding ob_start() before your function return statement and get all contents with $content = ob_get_contents(), clean buffer and finally return $content to prevent those unexpected results

Comment: I did that my stopwatch disappears

Comment: Sorry i've edited and adding missing echo statement try it again please